# FPDF rounded rectangle

Tags: php, fpdf

I need to create a rounded rectangle in FPDF like [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script7.php). But I also want it to be possible to enter text or even QR codes in there,so far I haven't found a solution.

- How to make a rounded rectangle where I can insert anything (text, images, etc.)?
- or How to make the line bend (as I really need this for background purposes only)?

Comment: How have you tried to solve this issue so far?  (I suspect you'll probably have to insert images because I don't think FPDF supports fancy effects)

Comment: You should be able to do it with the code you provided (script7.php). Elements will be layered on each other, so you can first add the custom form via `RoundedRect()`, then add more elements into the provided x/y/z coordinate space.

Comment: you can create another function which accepts the parameters to create a rounded rectangle and a string for the text. First it draws the rounded rectangle then it calls the cell() function to draw some text perfectly aligned http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm. Of course you have to disable the borders for the cell

Comment: @GordonM I did, but now it's fixed. thank you.